# What am I missing to center this div for an email template

Tags: html, css, wordpress, html-email

It's an email template, so I think I should avoid flex. Any idea why this isn't centered?

```
<div style="display:inline-block; margin: 0 auto;">
  <div style="background-color: #0097e6; border-radius:30px; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400; padding: 8px 24px 8px 24px; text-align: center; margin: 24px 10px 5px 10px ;">
    <a href="https://example.com/" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff;">See related</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RichardU/7Lhupo3x/6/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it's an option for you but changing

```
display: inline-block;
```

to

```
display: table;
```

would align the button in the center of the container.

Comment: That did it. Thanks.

Comment: This does *not* work on Outlook desktops. The button itself is the full width of the container.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for email, you'll want to use tables, because Outlook.

To centre, you'll need the table have a width smaller than the element you are centering in, necessitating `max-width` for mobile responsiveness.

Then, because Outlook (desktop) does not recognise max-width, you'll need an Outlook table wrapper.

```
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            <table width="600" align="center" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-spacing:0;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;color:#333333;" >
            <tr>
            <td style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;border-collapse:collapse;" >
            <![endif]-->
<table style="margin:0 auto;width:100%;max-width:600px;"> <!--Core centering code -->
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div style="background-color: #0097e6; border-radius:30px; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400; padding: 8px 24px 8px 24px; text-align: center; margin: 24px 10px 5px 10px ;">
    <a href="https://example.com/" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff;">See related</a>
  </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <![endif]-->
```

Comment: I expect this is all correct but I can't test it because the bulk of the email is fixed by my provider, I'm just feeding it via RSS. Cheers.